# Goroutine: time.Sleep or time.After

Tags: go

I wonder what is the better way to do a wait in a goroutine, `time.Sleep()` or `<-time.After()`?  What's the difference between the two and how to make choices? Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't think it matters much for the majority of programs. There has been a [question on golang-nuts about this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/9BL6v7Nqj_I) but I don't think one can draw any conclusion.

In practice `After` is useful in contexts where one already needs to `select` on a number of channels but would also like a timeout:

```
select {
case c := <-someChan:
  ..
case c := <-otherChan:
  ..
case <-time.After(time.Second * 42):
}
```

By superficially looking at the code `Sleep` seems simpler while `After` builds a new timer, with a period, a closure to send the time when it finishes etc.

Again, I don't think it matters in practice but `time.Sleep` seems pretty readable so I would go with that.

---

On my implementation both of them perform the exact same system calls and end up waiting:

```
futex(??, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, {41, 999892351}
                          ^^ 41 seconds and change
```

Answer (score 9):

Per [go101](https://go101.org/article/unofficial-faq.html#time-sleep-after)

> The two will both pause the current goroutine execution for a certain duration. The difference is the function call `time.Sleep(d)` will let the current goroutine enter sleeping sub-state, but still stay in [running state](https://go101.org/article/control-flows-more.html#states-of-goroutine), whereas, the channel receive operation `<-time.After(d)` will let the current goroutine enter blocking state.

---

Update **08/15/2022**

The difference from go dev

- [time.After](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.After)

```
 After waits for the duration to elapse and then sends the current time on the returned channel.
 It is equivalent to `NewTimer(d).C`.
 The underlying Timer is not recovered by the garbage collector
 until the timer fires. If efficiency is a concern, use `NewTimer`
 instead and call `Timer.Stop` if the timer is no longer needed.
```

- [time.Sleep](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Sleep)

```
Sleep pauses the current goroutine for at least the duration d. A negative or zero duration causes Sleep to return immediately.
```

---

As @cnicutar pointed out that

> After is useful in contexts where one already needs to select on a number of channels but would also like a timeout

Here is another details example to compare `time.After` with `time.Sleep` within `select`

```golang
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func cancelAfter(interval time.Duration, cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    go func(cancel context.CancelFunc) {
        time.Sleep(interval)
        fmt.Println("cancel task at ", time.Now())
        cancel()
        wg.Done()
    }(cancel)
}

func TestTimerSleep(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    wg.Add(1)
    cancelAfter(time.Second*15, cancel)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                fmt.Println("TimerSleep is cancelled", time.Now())
                wg.Done()
                return
            default:
                time.Sleep(time.Second * 6)
                fmt.Println("time sleep", time.Now())
            }
        }
    }(ctx)
    wg.Wait()
}

func TestTimerAfter(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    wg.Add(1)
    cancelAfter(time.Second*15, cancel)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                fmt.Println("TimerAfter is cancelled", time.Now())
                wg.Done()
                return
            case <-time.After(time.Second * 6):
                fmt.Println("time after", time.Now())
            }
        }
    }(ctx)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Results

```
TestTimerSleep

time sleep 2022-08-15 15:43:56.502134 
time sleep 2022-08-15 15:44:02.502682 
cancel task at  2022-08-15 15:44:05.501721 
time sleep 2022-08-15 15:44:08.503892 
TimerSleep is cancelled 2022-08-15 15:44:08.50393 


TestTimerAfter
time after 2022-08-15 15:44:55.089277
time after 2022-08-15 15:45:01.0905
cancel task at  2022-08-15 15:45:04.089352
TimerAfter is cancelled 2022-08-15 15:45:04.089432
```

From the results, the `time.After` could be canceled immediately when time out.

Comment: I'm not sure which it is saying is better but it sounds like it is saying time.After().  That is outdated or incorrect.  time.Sleep() is preferred. BTW Go101 is a great site but it does have a few errors.

Comment: @AndrewW.Phillips, thank you very much for pointing out what I am missing. I have updated my answer, if anything missing, please let me know.